# How to select latest records from multiple tables Mysql Php

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have three tables and i want to get records according to datetime for all tables,

Here is my table "users"

```
id      name
1       abc
2       xyz
```

Here is my table "paymentHistory"

```
id      bookingId           userId          createdOn
1       101                 1               2020-07-10 12:11:14
2       102                 1               2020-07-11 10:31:19 
3       105                 1               2020-07-11 12:31:19 
4       109                 2               2020-07-10 11:45:32
```

Here is my table "cancelPaymentHistory"

```
id      bookingId           userId          createdOn
1       103                 1               2020-07-07 11:31:28
2       100                 1               2020-07-11 11:31:28
3       109                 2               2020-07-08 19:28:41
```

Here is my table "usr_booking"

```
id      bookingId           userId          status          created_on
1       104                 1               Inprocess       2020-07-07 10:31:28
```

Now i want to get all record where userId='1' and according to createdOn (DESC) of three tables
How can i do this ?

I tried with following code but showing so many records( showing wrong result)

```
SELECT u.id as userId,ph.bookingId as paymentHistoryBooking,cph.bookingId as CancelBookingId,ub.bookingId as usrBooking
FROM users u
JOIN paymentHistory ph ON u.id=ph.userId
JOIN cancelPaymentHistory cph ON u.id=cph.id
JOIN usr_booking ub ON u.id=ub.userId
WHERE u.id='152'
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the output you're trying to get?

Comment: I don't see how that query could work at all, though. You're using `u` and `cph` in the query, but they aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: $Mureinik : i want record according to datetime , means whether record come from paymentHistory,usr_booking or cancelPaymentHistory should be display according to time ( DESC ) , hope you understand

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: Please check now , edit my question

Comment: That makes me believe that you haven't copy/pasted your actual code. Always copy/paste the real code without rewriting it, or you might introduce new issues (like the one I pointed out) or even accidentally fix potential issue you have in the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not correct.
First you miss the alias `u` of the `users` table so the second row must look like:

`FROM users u`

Second, in the the fourth row you accidently wrote `u.id = cph.id`, but you want to match with the `userId`, not the `cancelPaymentHistory.id`. Additionally you miss the alias for the `cancelPaymentHistory` table. So the correct fourth line must look like:

`JOIN cancelPaymentHistory cph ON u.id = cph.userId`

The whole query would look like:

```
SELECT u.id as userId,ph.bookingId as paymentHistoryBooking,cph.bookingId as CancelBookingId,ub.bookingId as usrBooking 
FROM users u
JOIN paymentHistory ph ON u.id=ph.userId
JOIN cancelPaymentHistory cph ON u.id=cph.userId
JOIN usr_booking ub ON u.id=ub.userId
WHERE u.id='152';
```

To order your result by the latest `createdOn` of all tables, you must first identify the latest `createdOn` of all tables:

```
SELECT userId, max(createdOn) as latestActivity
(SELECT userId, max(createdOn) as createdOn
FROM cancelPaymentHistory
UNION
SELECT userId max(createdOn) as createdOn
FROM usr_booking
UNION 
SELECT userId max(createdOn) as createdOn
FROM paymentHistory)
```

This result must be joined with the prior query:

```
SELECT u.id as userId,ph.bookingId as paymentHistoryBooking,cph.bookingId as CancelBookingId,ub.bookingId as usrBooking 
, max(latestActivity)
FROM users u
JOIN paymentHistory ph ON u.id=ph.userId
JOIN cancelPaymentHistory cph ON u.id=cph.userId
JOIN usr_booking ub ON u.id=ub.userId
JOIN (SELECT userId, max(createdOn) as latestActivity
     FROM (SELECT userId, max(createdOn) as createdOn
     FROM cancelPaymentHistory
     UNION
     SELECT userId, max(created_on) as created_on
     FROM usr_booking
     UNION 
     SELECT userId, max(createdOn) as createdOn
     FROM paymentHistory) a) activity ON activity.userId = u.id
WHERE u.id='1'
ORDER BY activity.latestActivity DESC;
```

Note, that I still got the `ORDER BY` in the query. I am assuming you want to run this statement for multiple users, so you can modify the `WHERE`-Statement like
`WHERE u.id IN ('1','2','3')` and still have a sorted list.

I have set up a fiddle for you http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea835a/28/0

Comment: OfNine: but where is orderby ? i want to get record according to createdOn (dateTime) in Assending order

Comment: From which table `createdOn` should originate from?

Comment: i want to use createdOn for all tables means i want to get records according to date time , i want to show records to user according to his activity time

Comment: you want to order by the latest `createdOn` of a user in all tables? As the user table probably holds every user once, you will have one record for every user in the results. Ordering by multiple columns is semantically nonsense in this case.

Comment: yes you are right ( and your query still giving me too many records which is wrong )

Comment: Are you sure, that every user is only once in the users table? And do you want the latestActivity (max(createdOn)) in the results?

Comment: yes i am sure , all users have unique id (auto incremented) , bookingId is also unique for all tables

Comment: please check table and query on db-fiddle.com and let me know

Comment: your updated query giving me following error 

" Unknown column 'userId' in 'field list'

Comment: I have setup a fiddle for you, check out my modified answer. I am still not sure if this is the desired result. Maybe you try to clarify how your result should look like?

Comment: let me try to explain, 

1)    i cancelled booking at 2020-07-11   09:10:20 ( stored record in "paymentCancell table)
2 )   i completed booking at 2020-07-05 11:22:34  ( stored record in "paymentHistory table")
3)   My booking is "inProcess" at 2020-07-11 19:12:11 ( stored record in usr_booking table)  

Now i want all record + according to my activity time ( present time to past ) 

Now result should be like 

3) Inprocess  (2020-07-11 19:12:11)
1) Booking cancelled 2020-07-11   09:10:20
2) Booking complete (2020-07-05 11:22:34) 
 

Hope you understand my point

Comment: in my "usr_booking" userId is "user_id" (please change in your fiddle and try then )

Comment: You really should work on the way you are asking questions. It is hard to understand what you want to achieve plus your question does not mirror your setup. I cannot help you like that. What do you mean by (present time to past) what past? Before I try another time to find out what you want, you have to edit your question with an example result. Thank you. And correct the tables, so that they are matching your actual setup.

Comment: actually i want latest record from all tables thats why i said "present to past" , i want all record ( latest to previous) , this is just simple question

Comment: It might be a simple question, but you are not able to ask it in a way so someone else could understand it. So please edit your question.